# Primary key not autogenerated using Room's Entity

Tags: android, primary-key, android-room

I'm using Room Entity framework for a class called User and I set the user ID to be autogenerated.

I tried to create an user object using the ONLY constructor, since Room cannot pick between multiple constructors.

My class looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "user_id")
    private Integer userID;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    public User(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Integer getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setUserID(Integer userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

The object is created just like this:
`User user = new User("Gabriel", "Johnson");`

I expected the ID to be 1, as I guess it will be incremented with every user that is created, beginning from 1. But the ID is null, the auto generation never happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Room only auto generates the key when the object is inserted into the database - even then, it doesn't fill out your key in the object you inserted.

You should only expect the userId to be filled out when reading an entity from the database.